# A Marvelous Meal

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, real

> S.H.I.E.L.D.
>   Universe
>   Okoye
>   Ironman
>   Cosmic
>   Invisible-Girl
>   Lois-Lane
>   Electra
>   Deadpool
>   Yellowjacket
>   Logan
>   Loki
>   Ant-man
>   Captin-America
>   Infinity-Warfare
>   Groot
>   Avengers
>   Marvel

So tell me,

> What did I eat for breakfast?

Comment: Did you just eat the whole super hero team XD

Comment: Lol, Nope what I ate is edible :D

Comment: Ok, gonna keep on thinking :D

Comment: When I read the title, I thought _everything_ listed would only be related to **Marvel**. Then I noticed [Lois-Lane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lois_Lane) :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you eat

> Lucky Charms? (So you’re the fellow who’s after [his](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Charms#/media/File%3ALucky%2C_the_Leprechaun_(General_Mills'_mascot).jpg) Lucky Charms!)

Because

> The acrostic is *Magically Delicious*!!

Comment: Yup, you got it correct!!! They live up to their slogan :D

Comment: Yay!! @QuantumTwinkie You’re making me hungry for some, I haven’t had those in forever! :D

Comment: I never noticed that! $(+1)$